# How to find out the value of 'n' in the equation (ΔG = −nFE)?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, nernst-equation

I can figure out the value of 'n' in simple equations like 
Fe³⁺ + e⁻ → Fe²⁺ (which would be n=1 here.)

But in equations like 2Cu⁺→ Cu²⁺ + Cu, I can't figure it out. I assumed the value of n would be 2 here as two electrons are involved in the disproportionation reaction, but my book says n=1 here. Can anyone help me understand what is the value of 'n' in this equation? Thank you.

Comment: One $\ce{Cu+}$ transfers an electron to the other, thus n=1.

Comment: Why two electrons? You strip an electron from one Cu and give the same one electron to another Cu.

Comment: Oh, I understand where I was going wrong. I looked at the electrons on both sides of the equation. Thank you!